# Chrome Extensions Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Okay so I'm trying to set options for my Chrome extension.  I don't know why this is failing, but here's my code. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

options.html

```
<html>
<head><title>PT'd Settings</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Saves options to localStorage.
function save_options() {
  var select = document.getElementById("show");
  var option = select.children[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage["show"] = option;

  // Update status to let user know options were saved.
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  status.innerHTML = "Options Saved: "+localStorage["show"]; //this shows up perfectly
  setTimeout(function() {
    status.innerHTML = "";
  }, 750);
}

// Restores select box state to saved value from localStorage.
function restore_options() {
  var favorite = localStorage["show"];
  if (!favorite) {
    return;
  }
  var select = document.getElementById("show");
  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++) {
    var child = select.children[i];
    if (child.value == favorite) {
      child.selected = "true";
      break;
    }
  }
}

</script>

<body onload="restore_options()">

When to show image:
<select id="show">
 <option value="load">Show on Load</option>
 <option value="click">Show on Click</option>
</select>

<br>
<button onclick="save_options()">Save</button>
<br />
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I need to send that option to my injected javascript

background.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {set: localStorage["show"]}, function(response) {
        document.getElementById("box").value = response.answer; //just for testing purposes
    });
});
document.write(localStorage["show"]); //just for testing purposes
</script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

injected javascript

```
...
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("set "+request.set); //never even runs
    if(request.show == "click") {
        //calculate "found" value and send it back
        sendResponse({answer: found});
    }
});
...
```

So I'm not even sure if the background.html page can read the localStorage, but I do know for a fact that it's not properly sending *any* variables to the javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Just had to add permissions to the manifest

`"permissions": ["tabs"]`

Google Chrome's documentation is kind of weak.

Comment: If it's not giving you the information you need, we should improve it. What about the documentation was confusing or lacking?

Please do file bugs (on documentation or anything else) via http://new.crbug.com/

Comment: That was four years ago. And the documentation for Chrome extensions is still very weak.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I quite get what you are up to but... perhaps the "[getBackgroundPage](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage)" method might set off a light bulb?

getBackgroundPage() allows you to share JS state between your extension pages (sort of like a module if you've used node or requireJS)... I use it in my popup.htm to grab and display any data my background.htm has collected. From background.htm I am alerting the user via extension badge and desktopnotifications.

Hope it helps!